# Fortran pythagorean trigonometric identity not working at times

Tags: debugging, fortran, codeblocks, gfortran

I'm using Codeblocks + GNU Fortran.

The problem is that I have calculations like:

```
SQRT(1-COS*COS)
```

And when I do these calculations a lot (a few million times) sometimes the value under square root is negative and therefore I get NaNs in result.

My efforts have shown that when square root is being calculated for a negative number COS equals "-1". Therefore, fortran counts -1*-1 incorrectly as there should be 0 under square root but there isn't.

Is there a way to solve this problem? This concerns not only pythagorean trigonometric identity but anything under square root looking like

```
SQRT(1-x*x)
```

With X being in range of [-1,1].

Basically COST is defined like this in my program (I apologize for somewhat lengthy introduction before COST itself but that's how it goes):

```
XDET = 0.
YDET = 0.
ZDET = 50.
RADIUS = 1.

x = RADIUS*sqrt(omega)  !omega=random number in uniform distribution [0,1]
y = 0.
z = 1.E-20

DW=SQRT((XDET-X)**2+(YDET-Y)**2+(ZDET-Z)**2)
DWW = 1./DW
AN2=(ZDET-Z)*DWW

COST = AN2
if(COST > 1. ) COST = 1.
if(COST < -1.) COST = -1.
SINT = SQRT(1.-COST*COST)
```

By the way, the AN2 sometimes assumed an absolute zero that lead to NaNs as well before I trapped it.

P.S. I also have a bug of EXP(X) with X being higher than 90 showing up as INFINITY.

Comment: How certain are you that |`COS`| can never be greater than 1.0?

Comment: Show us your code.  As it stands the expression `SQRT(1-COS*COS)` can only be parsed successfully if `COS` is the name of a variable, it is not a call to the intrinsic function `COS`, nor to any other function.  While AlexanderVogt may be on the right lines, I'm reserving judgement.

Comment: High Performance Mark, see the edited post for code excerpt.

Comment: Can you please specify your gfortran version and values of omega that caused the problem?   I tested 1000 random numbers but have not been able to reproduce that problem.

Comment: Xiaolei Zhu, I am sorry for stupid question but how do I determine my gfortran version if it's been installed with Codeblocks?

Comment: do `gfortran --version` in the terminal should do it.  the value of `omega` is likely more helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanation for what your PS identifies as a bug is simple

```
exp(90.0) > 3.4028235 x 10^38
```

and `3.4028235 x 10^38` is the largest positive number that a single-precision floating-point number can represent with any accuracy.

This analysis does, of course, assume that your variable `x` is an IEEE 32-bit floating-point number.

Note too, that the expression `ZDET-Z` will never, in single-precision, be different from `1.0`.  `1.0 - 1.0e-20 == 0.9999999999999999999` but representing this exactly exceeds the precision available and the number is rounded to `1.0`.

While I still can't see how `1.-COST*COST` would ever be negative your use of floating-point arithmetic isn't reassuring me that there aren't subtle mistakes in those parts of the code you haven't shown us.

Comment: Yeah, I've come to the same conclusion when I reckoned how much exp(90+) really is. Thank you.

Comment: Well, I am not really a great specialist on f-p arithmetic particularly considering that most of the code was provided by my scientific supervisor for me to be able to do my scientific work.
If you could specify what I should correct to make the program more stable, I'd gladly do it as I'm fixing things here and there in the code as I learn more about Fortran.

Comment: You should, if you haven't already, familiarise yourself with the Wikipedia article on floating-point.  The paper to which Alexander Vogt points you, which is often pointed to, is highly technical and probably not a good first read on the topic.  Once you understand what Wikipedia tells you, learn about Fortran's capabilities in this regard.  Pay particular attention to the definition and use of numeric `kinds`.  Study a text on numerical computation, I like Hamming's book *Numerical Methods for Scientists and Engineers* but there are many others.

Comment: You can't do your scientific work without a good understanding of floating-point numbers and arithmetic any more than you can do it without a good understanding of (the relevant) mathematics.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be this is due to limited precision of floating point numbers. Take a look here: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Simple solution:

```
xx = x*x
if ( xx .gt. 1.e0 ) xx = 1.e0 ! 1.d0 for double precision

y = sqrt( 1.e0 - xx ) ! Again, 1.d0 for double precision
```

Or, as a one-liner:

```
 y = sqrt( 1.e0 - min( x*x, 1.e0 ) )
```

Comment: Except the domain of cosine is [-1.0, 1.0], which should, when squared, result in a domain of [0.0, 1.0]. There should be no possibility of a negative argument to the function.

Comment: Mark is right. Also for integer valued real variables the arithmetic is usually exact.